# Need a clarification of the definition $\tilde d(p_1,p_2)=\inf\{\tilde L(\gamma):\gamma(0)=p_1,\ \gamma(1)=p_2\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

[image]

I cannot understand the definition of $\tilde d(p_1,p_2)$ here? Can anyone please explain it clearly?

Answer (score 2):

As in differential geometry, we are defining the "distance" between two points to be the inf of the "lengths" of all paths joining the points. (For example, with the usual notion of lengths of paths in $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, what is the distance from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$? Note that you cannot use the usual line segment joining them.)

Comment: But the distance is 2, right?

Comment: Yes, even though there's no path of length $2$ joining those points, because the origin is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The definition given is $\bar{d}(p_1,p_2) = \inf\{\bar{L}(\gamma) : \gamma(0) = p_1, \gamma(1) = p_2\}$.

The condition $\gamma(0) = p_1$, $\gamma(1) = p_2$ means the curve $\gamma(t)$ starts at point $p_1$ and ends at point $p_2$.

Since $\bar{L}(\gamma)$ is the "length" of the curve $\gamma$, $\{\bar{L}(\gamma) : \gamma(0) = p_1, \gamma(1) = p_2\}$ is the set of all possible "lengths" of curves which start at $p_0$ and end at $p_1$.

Therefore, $\bar{d}(p_1,p_2) = \inf\{\bar{L}(\gamma) : \gamma(0) = p_1, \gamma(1) = p_2\}$ is the infimum (greatest lower bound) of the "lengths" of all curves which start at $p_1$ and end at $p_2$.

---

Note that the "length" of a curve is defined as $\bar{L}(\gamma) = \displaystyle\int_{\gamma}|x|\,ds = \int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\,dt$ instead of the usual definition $L(\gamma) = \displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\,ds = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\,dt$. With this definition, the length of a small segment of a curve is weighted by the absolute value of its $x$-coordinate.

Hence, the distance between two points $\bar{d}(p_1,p_2) = \inf\{\bar{L}(\gamma) : \gamma(0) = p_1, \gamma(1) = p_2\}$ is no longer the usual straight line Euclidean distance that you are used to seeing.

To compute $\bar{d}((1,1),(-1,-2))$, you'll need to figure our the infimum of the "lengths" of curves from $(1,1)$ to $(-1,-2)$. If you can come up with a curve from $(1,1)$ to $(-1,-2)$ and show that its "length" is less than the "length" of any other curve from $(1,1)$ to $(-1,-2)$, you'll have your answer. Hint: What is the "length" of any straight line segment that lies entirely on line $x = 0$? Use this fact to your advantage when deciding on what might be the curve from $(1,1)$ to $(-1,-2)$ with the least length.

Comment: I think this answer is excellent. Just wanted to tell @Mathi to prove the existence of "inf" (so you know the definition is, in fact, well-defined) by using the hypothesis of a smooth curve.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: So, is $\tilde d ((1,1),(-1,-2))= \sqrt{(1-(-1))^2+(1-(-2))^2}$?

Comment: No, it's quite different. For starters, what's the "distance" from $(0,-2)$ to $(0,3)$?

Comment: Why is it wrong? So, please tell me how to find $\tilde d((1,1),(−1,−2))$?

Comment: Ok so, as I understand here $\displaystyle \tilde d ((1,1),(-1,-2))=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{13}x \;dx=0$. Am I correct?

Comment: ^I'm pretty sure that's not right. What curve $\gamma(t)$ did you use to get that?

Comment: The straight line joining two points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-2)$

Comment: That straight line can be parametrized as $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ where $x(t) = 1-2t$, $y(t) = 1-3t$. So its length is $\bar{L}(\gamma) = \int_{0}^{1}|1-2t|\sqrt{13}\,dt = \sqrt{13}/2$ which is not $0$. Also, that isn't the smallest length possible. Try the curve which goes from $(1,1)$ to $(0,1)$ to $(0,-2)$ to $(-1,-2)$ in straight line segments.

Comment: How did you find that the latter curve you said gives the smallest length? Please tell me.

Comment: I didn't say that latter curve gives the smallest length possible. But it does give a smaller length than the straight line segment from $(1,1)$ to $(-1,-2)$.

Comment: So if you know how to find it, can you please tell me it? I am so confused now.